# Sorting of structures using elementary methods

Tags: c++, c

This is the program which totals the marks of each student and sorts the total but does not swap the order of other parameters such as student name, and their subject marks. How to sort the structure as a whole while keeping the total marks as basis for sorting? I don't want to use any built in functions and do it by elementary methods.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct stnd
{
   int sub[20];
   char name[20];
   int total;
}
stnd[20];
main()
{
    int i, j, n=4, m=4,k;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            scanf("%d",&stnd[i].sub[j]);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf(" %s",stnd[i].name);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        stnd[i].total=0;
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            stnd[i].total=stnd[i].total+stnd[i].sub[j];
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(stnd[i].total<stnd[j].total)
            {
                k=stnd[i].total;
                stnd[i].total=stnd[j].total;
                stnd[j].total=k;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Rank\t Chin\t Math\t Eng\t Comp\t total\t name\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",i+1);
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        printf("%d\t",stnd[i].sub[j]);
        printf("%d\t",stnd[i].total);
        printf("%s\t\n",stnd[i].name);

    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function where you're swapping, just swap the structure instead of the total:

```
// Where you declare k, declare it as a struct stnd
struct stnd k;

// Where you swap, just swap the structures, not the totals
k = stnd[i];
stnd[i]  stnd[j];
stnd[j] = k;
```

When you set a `struct stnd`, it does a bitwise copy of the object you're copying, which is exactly what you need for the sorting.

Comment: I want to point out that this isn't *always* what you want. This makes a shallow copy. It will work in *this* case, but understanding **why** it works and **how** and **when** it wouldn't is extremely important.

Comment: @NikBougalis Actually, I feel a need to clarify your clarification.  If you're doing something like copying a row of data, yes, you'd have to be cautious about performing a shallow copy.  I can't think of any instance *when sorting* when you don't want a shallow copy, though.  Since you're swapping, the intent is to "move" the data, not copy it, and shallow copying is perfect for a "move" operation.